# Action after clicking Delete button

Tags: confirmation

Action after delete button should be:

`yes -  no`

or:

`Delete - cancel`

Which colors (Red,Green) should be used with buttons?

Which one should be Red and which one should be Green?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very much depending on the design ecosystem you're working with within the brand. However, I would suggest the following:

- Upon clicking on the Delete button, triggering the action, a confirmation shows up "Are you sure you would like to delete {item name}?" This confirms that you have triggered the delete action and that you are about to delete something.
- Two buttons aligned to the bottom right of the confirmation; in the far right, a red button with the copy "Delete" and next to that, on the left side, a neutral-coloured button saying "Cancel". The red button visually confirms the action, whereas the neutral (grey?) button suggests alternative actions that can be taken.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest Using one of Google's design Principles which goes like

> **Decide for me but let me have the final say**
>
> Take your best guess and act rather than asking first. Too many
>   choices and decisions make
>    people unhappy. Just in case you get it wrong, allow for 'undo'.

Google has implemented this in both of its Android and iOS Gmail app. When you delete something it doesn't ask for your confirmation like "Are you sure ? ". It rather deletes the file (decides for you), and then provides with the option to UNDO(let me have the final say) it . The undo option is pronounced with the help of eye catching colors and is visible for some amount of calculated seconds, enough to realize if you've made a mistake.

Answer (score 0):

This will obviously depends on the system you are currently developing. But based on the normal user perceptions, **Yes** button should be green and **No** button should be Red or Neutral.

The **Delete** button should be of Red Color as it should warn the user before deleting and the **Cancel** button should be Neutral.